# What does this mean, "External reset input, active low. Must be asserted for a minimum of 10 µs."?

Tags: usb

Looking at this USB Hub controller IC, [XR22404](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/146/XR22404-1006299.pdf), page 5. More confused on the second statement, what does it mean to be asserted for a min of 10 us?

Comment: S = siemens. s = second.

Comment: I think that is one of the reasons I was confused. I suspect they made the mistake of using S instead of the traditional s for seconds.

Answer (score 3):

It means if you want to reset the chip correctly, you can't just assert the reset signal for 5 us, or 7 us, or 9 us. You have to assert it for at least 10 us, or the device might not reset, or might not reset correctly.

Comment: Also, just for clarity (the OP may not understand this), it must be held to within the limit range of \$V_\text{LOW}\$ -- which is what "active low" means. "Asserting it" means "active" and in this case "active" means "LOW."

Comment: This can be controlled by either a Raspberry PI GPIO pin or a pull-up resistor with a grounding switch correct? When the pin is grounded is when the reset occurs?

Comment: Do the RPi outputs meet the input level requirements of the other chip? (I have no idea if RPi has 3.3 or 5 V I/Os) If they do, you should be able to hook the RPi GPIO directly to this chip.